# Can't find path to script being executed by TCL interpreter since info script returns empty string

Tags: tcl, quartus

I need path of the script being executed by the TCL interpreter. I have used the "info script" but it returns empty string! I have also tried to use shell commands but they don't work from the tcl interpreter program at all for reasons I do not understand yet. I am trying to do this in "System Console" found in Intel Quartus Prime Standard.

What alternative exists? I am using the GUI and select the script from a window that appears after selecting the "Execute Script" command.

Comment: The `info script` command returns the empty string when there's no `source` (or C API equivalent) active on the stack.

Comment: @DonalFellows is it correct to use `info script` that way inside a **starkit** executable? I use it mainly to get the root path of the internal VFS, so that I can copy files stored inside to the "outside" real filesystem.

Comment: @Losko It's correct wherever; one of the features of the whole VFS abstraction is that things work as close to the same when virtualised as when on a real filesystem. It's only for a few things (like files that get handed to other programs or raw to the underlying OS calls) that you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get useful information out of `info script` while that Tcl file is actively running, *not* when calling the procedures it defines later on. It's fairly common to put this in your source file:

```bash
variable thisFile [file normalize [info script]]
# Normalizing converts to an absolute path and sorts out all the symbolic links
```

That works very well when the file also defines a namespace, common good practice for any vaguely library code.

But if you've not got that, what can you do anyway? Well... if you have 8.6 (or later) then you have an option.

```
% parray tcl_platform
tcl_platform(byteOrder)     = littleEndian
tcl_platform(engine)        = Tcl
tcl_platform(machine)       = x86_64
tcl_platform(os)            = Darwin
tcl_platform(osVersion)     = 20.4.0
tcl_platform(pathSeparator) = :
tcl_platform(platform)      = unix
tcl_platform(pointerSize)   = 8
tcl_platform(threaded)      = 1
tcl_platform(wordSize)      = 8
% dict get [tcl::unsupported::getbytecode proc parray] sourcefile
/opt/local/lib/tcl8.6/parray.tcl
```

You can also pick the information out of the result of `tcl::unsupported::disassemble` if you really like string processing, but `getbytecode` is easier. The information is not there in Tcl 8.5 and earlier (nor is `getbytecode`).

Comment: I shall look into this as well now. I was wrongly assuming that $::argv0 would be the medicine for all my ailments.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
pwd
```

Return the absolute path of the current working directory.

Source: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/pwd.htm

So you probably should do this:

```
set current_path [file nativename [pwd]]
```

Bye

Comment: This does not seem to work as it just gives me path to the interpreter. I am rather surprised to see that the Intel Quartus Prime System Console does not do this correctly.